# Sum of elements in ragged array

Tags: java

I am writing a code that computes the sum of all elements in the array `Volt`. Here is my code so far:

```
public class Volt{
  int[][] volt;

  public Volt(int[][] volt){
    this.volt = volt; 
  }

  public int sum(){
    int sum = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i <volt.length; i++) {
      for( int r = 0; r <volt.length; r++){
      sum += volt[i][r];
      }
    }
    return sum;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    int[][] a1 = { { 10, 5 }, { 2, 8 } };
    Volt m1 = new Volt(a1);
    System.out.println(m1.sum());

  }
}
```

However, I would like to make it work even if the `volt` matrix is ragged, with not all rows containing the same number of columns. I did quite a bit of research to get the the point I am at now but what I have now might need changing. I'd appreciate some help :) 
Thanks!

Comment: Simple. In line 11 of your code, replace `volt.length` with `volt[i].length`.

Comment: I guess you don't know that a 2D array in Java is just an array of arrays, whose elements can be replaced with other arrays.

Comment: You guys are incredible! Thanks!
By the way what does 'ragged' actually mean? Does it mean uneven?

Comment: Accept the answer and get free reputation! (Well, not really free.)

Comment: A *jagged* array is an array of arrays in which the individual 1D array elements have different lengths. (See my comment above.)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of looping to `volt.length` in the inner for-loop, just loop to the length of the array you're on with the outer loop, i.e. `volt[i].length`:

```
for( int r = 0; r <volt[i].length; r++){
```

By the way you can also use the enhanced for loop:

```
int sum = 0;

for (int[] a : volt)
    for (int i : a)
        sum += i;
```